# Some keys in session_kwargs are not supported at this time: %s', dict_keys(['metrices']))

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to make a Basic Image Classification Project which can differentiate between any two or multiple categories.
I have written following code and getting an error stated above in the title.
How can i solve this error?
Below is my code

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation,Dropout,Flatten,Dense
from keras import backend as k
import numpy as np

img_width,img_height = 64,64
train_data_dir = 'dataset/training_set'
validation_data_dir = 'dataset/test_set'
nb_train_samples = 1000
nb_validation_samples = 100
epochs = 50
batch_size = 20

if k.image_data_format() == 'channel-first':
   input_shape = (3,img_width,img_height)
else:
   input_shape = (img_width,img_height,3)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                      train_data_dir,
                                      target_size=(img_width,img_height),
                                      batch_size = batch_size,
                                      class_mode = 'binary')

validation_generator=test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                    validation_data_dir,
                                    target_size = (img_width,img_height),
                                    batch_size = batch_size,
                                    class_mode = 'binary')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),input_shape = input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
model.summary()

model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
#model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
#model.add(Activation('relu'))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
model.summary()

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.sgd(lr = 0.1)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer = optimizer,
              metrices = ['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                steps_per_epoch = nb_train_samples // batch_size,
                epochs = epochs,
                validation_data = validation_generator,
                validation_steps = nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
```

Each line is working fine,except this last section of code.
on running this last piece of code,
i am getting the following error

**('Some keys in session_kwargs are not supported at this time: %s', dict_keys(['metrices']))**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you be looking for `metrics` instead of `metrices`?